# form target=iframe is redirecting instead of loading

Tags: html, forms, iframe

I have an html form that has no javascript whatsoever, and I am trying to use an iframe to load the response.

My html looks like

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost:3000/post_transfer" target="something">
   <input type="text" name="user"/><input type="text" name="quantity"/>
   <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<iframe name="something" id="something"></iframe>
```

What I want to happen is that the form is submitted and the iframe is filled with the response and stays on the current page.

The iframe is filled as expected, but then redirects to the post_transfer page with a rails error. (The error does not occur if I remove `target=iframe` from the form, but I feel that is not relevant)

Here is a short clip: https://i.imgur.com/mhTClbL.mp4

Why is this happening and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Which browser do you use ? (+version)

Comment: I'm using Chromium 58 and is replicated in Firefox Nightly 60

Comment: What is the doctype used ? html 5?

Comment: yes, standard `<!doctype html>`

Comment: Does the response contain the X-XSS-Protection header?
The form does not need a csrf token?

Comment: @Alex83690 I think no? It's set to 0
`X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff`
`X-Request-Id: c2d54e5d-9eae-4674-be60-9f6dc2a711cc`
`X-Xss-Protection: 0`

Comment: @Alex83690 That fixed it! Make it an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sandbox html attribute on iframe to test if you can prevent redirection.

See https://w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp

If it works, it means that the targeted page ("http://localhost:3000/post_transfer") is sending redirection headers in the response.